# How to append a value on the same key in dictionary of python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to append a value to the same key in a dictionary.
(Finally, What I want to make is a dictionary with one key and two values)

```
keys = list(dictionary.keys())
for k in keys:
    dictionary.setdefault(k, []).append(0)
```

But it returns error:

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: create a new dictionary. The one you have already has int keys.

Comment: `setdefault` only produces the default value if the key doesn't exist, and every key you look at already exists in that dictionary (because that's where it came from).

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary already has values of `int` types; `dictionary.setdefault(k, [])` will returns the `int` object which does not have `append` method.

You need to convert `int` object to `list`.

- One way: use list of ints from the beginning instead int. (`[0]` instead of `0`)
- Other way: convert int to list before appending.

I recommend the first way for consistency.

Comment: By "`[0]` instead of `0`," you mean their original dictionary `dictionary`, right? With whatever integer value would've been used instead of `0`?

Comment: I meant value part of dictionary items: `{'key': [1234]}` instead of `{'key': 1234}`